# Type of wire needed for 250' run from 400 amp pedestal to 200 amp shop

Tags: wiring, underground

We are looking to run underground power for 200 amp service to our new shop that is about 250' away using aluminum wire. We are looking at running the wire in conduit. Would we use THWN-2 wire for this and if so, do you know what ground size would be best for this?

Comment: What size breaker are you putting in the main panel?

Comment: It is a 200 amp panel in the shop and the main pedestal is 400 amp

Comment: Those are _important_ details! Please [edit] your post to include them - not everyone reads comments.

Comment: I don't know the precise requirements, but a run that long may need a larger gauge.

Comment: The size of the breaker *in the main panel* is the determining factor. If your shop will never need more than 100A then the shop *sub*panel can have a 200A breaker *as a shutoff* + a 100A breaker on the feed to it in the *main* panel and then you can use much smaller wire. If, however, you actually need 200A (e.g., you are running a lot of big tools at the same time or have an EV charging next to the shop or have a big electric on-demand water heater (not a good idea...)) then you may actually need 200A feed and associated big wire.

Comment: What loads are you trying to run in said shop, and how big is it?

Answer (score 3):

My iPad won't let me comment. Ecnerwal is correct that the 310.15(B)(7) "favorable derate" does not help you.  Anyway, it operates off the service size not the feeder size, so if your service is 400A, it is saying no feeder needs to be larger than 600 kcmil. *Um, thanks NFPA, but that's... not helpful :)*

You could declare the feeder and garage load to be 180A.  You would use 180A wire (#4/0 aluminum) but since they don't make 180A breakers, you'd round up to the next available size - 200A.  Technically legal, but it ignores *voltage drop*.  Which will start to be an issue at this distance.

You are really better off using 250 kcmil.  It lets you call it an honest 200A feeder, and voltage drop will be less of an issue.  Still, at 160A (the maximum you can plan to use on a 200A feeder), voltage drop will be 3.9%.

4/0 or 250 kcmil wire requires a #2 aluminum ground.  (NEC 250.66).

If you are going to be pushing the limits of the 200A service, going up a size to 300 kcmil will take care of voltage drop (2.88% @ 160A).  When you bump the conductors you must bump the ground too in proportion, to #1 Al. (NEC 250.122(B).)

Answer (score 2):

You would use any suitable wet-rated wire, which might be THWN, THWN-2, XHW, XHHW, RHW (and there are others beyond those.)

Size of wires, grounding wire, conduit for wires all depends (firstly) on what the breaker supplying the power will be rated at. You've now commented that this will be 200A. With (typical, likely) 75 °C rated terminals at both ends this sets a minimum size of 250 kcmils for aluminum wire with an insulation rating of 75 °C or more.

Wire sizing ALSO depends (secondly) on the load calculation (which is not breaker size) for the loads to be supplied in the shop building.

The breaker sizing sets a minimum size of the wiring for any distance, no matter how short. The load calculation helps to determine if the wires should be increased in size at long distance, or if that's not needed.

Since the maximum load that can be planned on 200A service is 160A, and 160A has a voltage drop of well under 4% at 250 feet on 250 kcmil aluminum, we can skip extracting the details of your load to do a formal load calculation unless you are in Canada. Indeed, even 200A is under 5% loss.

Your grounding wire needs to be 2 AWG insulated aluminum based on the 250 kcmil  feeder. I don't believe a shop gets the "special derate for a dwelling service" that might allow smaller wiring (for both) but if I'm wrong one of the normal electricians will be along to correct that.

As a feeder, your neutral wire size can possibly be reduced, but only if a calculation supports that (it has to be at least as large as the required grounding conductor, and it has to be large enough to carry the maximum calculated unbalanced load (i.e. 120V loads all on one leg.)

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helps us out!